# Sending graphql mutations through elm

Tags: graphql, elm

I am trying to get my elm (v: 0.18) client to talk with my back-end via graphql.  I am trying to avoid the elm-graphql libraries for now, and the basic elm HttpBuilder module.

The login command looks like this:

```
loginCmd : Model -> Cmd Msg
loginCmd model =
    let
        graphiql =
            """
              mutation {
                login(email: "me@myapp.com", password: "password") {
                  token
                }
              }
            """
    in
        HttpBuilder.post ("http://localhost:4000/api")
            |> HttpBuilder.withStringBody graphiql
            |> HttpBuilder.withExpect (Http.expectJson myJsonDecoder)
            |> HttpBuilder.send GetTokenCompleted
```

The problem lies with the `withStringBody` function.  The compiler is sending me this:

```
The right side of (|>) is causing a type mismatch.

101|         HttpBuilder.post ("http://localhost:4000/api")
102|>            |> HttpBuilder.withStringBody graphiql

(|>) is expecting the right side to be a:

    RequestBuilder () -> a

But the right side is:

    String -> RequestBuilder a -> RequestBuilder a
```

I'm not sure what the problem is, given that the [HttpBuilder docs](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/lukewestby/elm-http-builder/1.0.0/HttpBuilder#withStringBody) say that it is of type `withStringBody : String -> RequestBuilder -> RequestBuilder`, and uses this as an example:

```
post "https://example.com/api/items/1"
  |> withHeader "Content-Type" "application/json"
  |> withStringBody """{ "sortBy": "coolness", "take": 10 }"""
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @P Ackerman is correct. Your documentation link is from an old version. At the top of the page it gives a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs, `withStringBody` actually takes `String -> String -> RequestBuilder a`, so I would say you need to add a content string before the `graphql` string, whatever would be appropriate for your `graphql` backend.

```
|> HttpBuilder.withStringBody "text/plain" """{ "sortBy": "coolness", "take": 10 }"""
```